# ¿Cómo paso un entero en un intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Estoy intentando hacer una pequeña aplicación de guardado de alumnos y notas, es muy sencilla, el tema es que no consigo averiguar como pasar un entero dentro de un intent, ya que con el método:

```
    String guardado_nota1 = dato_nota1.getText().toString();
```

Obviamente no funciona, ya que es para pasar una string, pero no encuentro el método de hacerlo.

```
public class addalumnos extends AppCompatActivity {

String [] array_nombres;
int [] array_nota1;
int [] array_nota2;
int [] array_nota3;
int contador;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_addalumnos);

    Intent adddatos = getIntent();
    array_nombres = adddatos.getStringArrayExtra("V1_array_noms");
    contador = adddatos.getIntExtra( "V2_contador", 0);

    final Button guardado = findViewById(R.id.guardado_datos);
    guardado.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText dato_nombre = findViewById(R.id.intro_nombre);
            String guardado_nombre = dato_nombre.getText().toString();

            EditText dato_nota1 = findViewById(R.id.intro_nota1);
            String guardado_nota1 = dato_nota1.getText().toString();

            EditText dato_nota2 = findViewById(R.id.intro_nota2);
            String guardado_nota2 = dato_nota2.getText().toString();

            EditText dato_nota3 = findViewById(R.id.intro_nota3);
            String guardado_nota3 = dato_nota3.getText().toString();

            array_nombres[contador] = guardado_nombre;
            array_nota1[contador] = guardado_nota1;
            array_nota2[contador] = guardado_nota2;
            array_nota3[contador] = guardado_nota3;
            contador++;

            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("V1_array_noms",array_nombres);
            returnIntent.putExtra("V2_contador",contador);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);


        }
    });
 }
}
```

Comment: Solucionado el problema

Comment: si encontraste la solucion, publica o explica, puede ser de ayuda para alguin mas :)